# Best method to call WCF services at interval

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, appfabric

I have several WCF services and I want to execute methods in them at specific intervals.

For example, call Service1.DoSomeWork every 5 minutes and Service2.DoSomeWork every 10 minutes. I also want Windows client applications to be able to call the DoSomeWork methods at any time.

What is the best way to implement this?

I have complete control over the server so using Scheduled Tasks is possible but I wonder if using a Workflow in AppFabric is better or using a timer in the service itself?

Comment: You could have a timer in an AppFabic WCF service but you run the risk that IIS will unload what it thinks is an idle ASP Application.  Just regularly hit the app with a web request to keep it alive or review the recycle settings for the AppPool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this post.  I answered a question a while ago where the developer want to "Do something" at an interval in a windows service.  I gave a pretty detailed code sample for scheduling activity within a Windows Service as recommended by other posted earlier in this thread.

[how to make service act dynamically based on service running condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594626/how-to-make-service-act-dynamically-based-on-service-running-condition/6594925#6594925)

Comment: Thanks GlennFerrieLive. The code provided is excellent. I am still curious if anyone out there is using AppFabric for such things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AppFabric but if I were you, I will use the timer since your requirement sounds simple.

Answer (score 0):

If I were your ,

I create a windows service in the server .

So that I can do anything at specific intervals....